# Creat table with d3.js and json data containing data and links

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, d3.js

I dont have a coding example of what i would like to achieve. But i have a serverside json that is requested from the client side. The data needs to be rendered as a table.
So far that would not be so difficult with d3.js. The problem is that some of the fields in the data are actually ID's belonging to a different data item. For example:
`{"date": "12-12-14", "name": "testname", "id": "1234"}`
the id is actually the url of the name, so in the table name should become a link with the url "id" and description "name". I hope that makes sense.

The question is: how can I use the data element of d3.js to distinguesh between data and being a link? My first idea was to make the whole table and let all the data be filled in. Then search for the ID and change the cells afterwards. But that does not seem to work in D3.js
Maybe it would be simpeler to make an easy for loop instead of using d3.js?

Comment: show code or no answers

Comment: I showed a piece of JSON code :-). But serious, i understand your comment, but had no idea what code to show in the first place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the data to create the link and name as below:

```
yourSelection
.append('a')
.attr({
    class: 'link',
    href: function (d) { return d.id; }
})
.html(function (d) { return d.name; });
```

Full example code in pen with your data format (not a table but list but showing proccess): http://codepen.io/eesur/pen/yYwQBj/

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for. I was thinking too complex :-). But realize now that i have a fixed layout, and i can append the cells according to it. I understand that the data explodes with every use of a function(d) call?

Comment: yes that's right, so `d` is looping like you may otherwise have done in a for loop—which would look more like `data[i].date`, or `data[i].name` etc This link explains it well and has example of accessing the index of the array too: https://www.dashingd3js.com/using-data-bound-to-dom-elements